# Add a single value to all records of new field using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, editing

Using ArcGIS Pro, how can I implement a new field with one value to all the records without having to insert it one by one?

Comment: Which software are you using? You are likely looking for the *Field Calculator*, or a similar function.

Comment: Hello Matt , I am using ArcGIS pro

Comment: For already existing object use field calculator, for object to be created you may set a default value to the relevant field…